# Azure WebJobs and Queue Related Metrics

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azureportal

I have looked around the Azure portal and searched the net, but I have been unable to find an answer.  Is there a way, perhaps via the api or powershell, to get metrics on webjobs?  Such as average runtime per individual job?  I would also like to find out the average queued time of a message that a webjob triggers from (though that is probably a storage metric not a webjob metric).  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Igorek said, I don't think it is possible either. There are many tools to monitor application. Two of them have Azure integration:

- [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/)
- [New relic](http://newrelic.com/azure)

I have used Application Insights to send metric from a webjob. You can follow this tutorial to setup Application insights n your webjob:

- [Application Insights on Windows Desktop apps, services and worker roles](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-desktop/)

If you want to calculate the time to process a message from a queue, you can do something like that:

```
public async Task ProcessAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("queueName")] BrokeredMessage incommingMessage)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    // Process your message
    ...

    stopwatch.Stop();

    // You should only instantiate the TelemetryClient once in your application.
    var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient() { InstrumentationKey = "MyInstrumentationKey"};

    //Send your metric
    telemetryClient.TrackMetric("ProcessQueueMessageElapsedTime", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I do use AI on our web site for general metrics, but I always forget that I can track custom metrics.

Comment: Yeah I have the same problem sometimes because I reset my brain every morning before arriving to the office ^^

Answer (score 2):

Don't think this is possible without 3rd party services.. in fact, the only one I know that does this stuff specifically is [CloudMonix](http://cloudmonix.com), which I'm affiliated with.